# Google maps inside Viewpager is bigger than screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-viewpager

I have a simple tab-layout (used gallary to generate the basics) where on one of the tabs a google maps is shown. Problem is that the viewpager seems to be bigger then the availible space. Result is that my zoom buttons of the map are half of the screen.

I tried al kinds changing the order of the layout XML and search the internet but so far nothing worked

My layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MemoryContainerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/Default.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Default.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/title_activity_view_memory">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

On tab1 and tab2 when i scroll the toolbar nicely moves up. But on tab 3 i have a fragment with the google-maps on it. Size properties are match-parent. So scrolling will just move me in the map (like i should) but does not move the toolbar.

the result is this:
[Sreen capture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAr8J.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

By lack of an better solution i solved it by splitting the above XML into and activity-XML and a content-XML.
Now it works but why??? i do not have an idea.